# need to update Ubuntu 10.1 to New 15.4?

Tags: upgrade

The Dell Windows 7 just died and I have a ThinkPad with new hard drive & Ubuntu 10.1. Can I update to Ubuntu 15.4? How? I can't figure out how to connect to WiFi (private secure connection). I realize it is an old computer but was refurbished. Geek that installed OS moved away and both computer stores can't help me with Linux. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10(I assume) to Ubuntu 15.04(I assume) a fresh install would definitely be the faster way.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is 5+ years old then be kind to both yourself & it, download Ubuntu Mate 15.04 or X-Ubuntu 15.04 image. Make a USB with it & install clean. The Unity desktop of the main Ubuntu flavor will likely be to heavy for your machine & a shock to your workflow. Attempting upgrading from 10.10 will just be a huge lot of hurt & aggravation

Answer (score 0):

Choose any more lightweight Ubuntu variant, and do a fresh install, if you have done a separate /home partition you don't even have to look for your data and back it all up. (of course do a backup, but not manually